# How to use UUID field in kwargs?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am new to Django and I am working on unit tests. This is my model:

```
class RandomModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    parent_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    parent_course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(
                                default=uuid.uuid4,
                                editable= False,
                                unique=True)
```

This is my urls.py

```
path('myPath/retrieve/<uuid:unique_id>', views.RetrieveABCAPIView.as_view(), name = myPath_retrieve)
```

I am trying the following in test.py

```
class APIStatusCodeTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Sets up testing environment. Add all endpoints to be tested
        """
        tbl = RandomModel.objects.create(title = 'rofl')
        tbl.save()

    self.retrieve_method_endpointsdeck = [
        reverse('flashcards:flashcards_api:myPath_retrieve', kwargs = {'unique_id': RandomModel.objects.unique_id('unique_id')})
```

What changes should I make to the reverse function? I don't know how to get UUID in kwargs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a `RandomModel` object in your test setup method, so you need to use the UUID for that object in `reverse` - something like this:

```
reverse(
    'flashcards:flashcards_api:myPath_retrieve', 
    kwargs={'unique_id': RandomModel.objects.first().unique_id}
)
```

Note that this will fetch the first `RandomModel` object that is found in the database - you probably want to be a bit more specific about which object you want to use - or create an object in this test itself.